# Is there a difference between the "stack frame" and the "function execution context" in the call stack?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused by the use of two terms that, from what I understand, point to the same concept, but are never related in articles I have read.

In [this first article about the call stack](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-the-javascript-call-stack-861e41ae61d4/), they say that:

> "When a function is invoked (called), the function, its parameters,
> and variables are pushed into the call stack to form a stack frame.
> This stack frame is a memory location in the stack. The memory is
> cleared when the function returns as it is pop out of the stack."

In [this second article about how JS works behind the scenes](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/execution-context-how-javascript-works-behind-the-scenes/), the author say that:

> "The JS engine then searches for function calls in the code. For each
> function call, a new FEC(=function execution context) is created for
> that function and is placed on top of the currently executing
> Execution Context.".

Does the function execution context is exactly the same as the stack frame **OR**

Does the function execution context "becomes" a so called stack frame when It goes to the call stack **OR**

Does the functions, parameters and variables (= variable environment) that partly constitute the function execution context are reference to the place they are stored in the "memory location in the stack", known as stack frame in the first article ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"When a function is invoked (called), the function, its parameters, and variables are pushed into the call stack to form a stack frame."* That's....not a good way to put it. :-|

Comment: Otherwise, I red this article about stack frame https://www.techopedia.com/definition/22304/stack-frame , but it doesn't help anyway. I think I understand what is stack frame and FEC but I don't get the difference or relation between them... Thanks for you answer !

Comment: The second article is pretty bad as well. "*The JS engine then searches for function calls in the code*" sounds just wrong. And the rest is full of inaccuracies as well - "*[a function execution context] does not construct a [variable object]. Rather, it generates an array-like object called the 'argument' object, which includes all of the arguments supplied to the function*" is outright wrong, as is "*… it doesn't create the `this` object. Rather, it get's access to that of the environment it is defined in.*"

Comment: And "*[In the execution phase,] the JavaScript engine reads the code in the current Execution Context once more, then updates the VO with the actual values of these variables. Then the code is parsed by a parser, gets transpired to executable byte code, and finally gets executed*" is just bullshit

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will search for better resources then.

Comment: "*Is the function execution context exactly the same as the stack frame?*" - yes. How exactly it is implemented in the interpreter (JS engine) is not defined though, i.e. whether it's a classical stack or rather a linked list, whether variable values are stored within the stack frame or just a reference to their environment record (scope), etc. This is all subject to optimisation.